# Should I choose a left-hand or right-hand drain bathtub if it's right next to the bathroom entry door to avoid rusting hinges?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, bathtub

I'm hoping to replace the shower in our bathroom with a tub/shower combo to better accommodate our small children and I need some advice about whether I should choose a left-hand drain alcove tub or a right-hand drain alcove tub.

The current set-up puts the shower head on the right, directly next to the entry door to the bathroom.

[image: Shower to the left of bathroom entry door]

Why don't I just use a right-hand drain tub and call it a day? Good question.

Our house was built in the early 50's, and originally had a left-hand drain tub and shower which the original owners replaced with this more accessible shower as they began to age-in-place in their later years.

If I went back to a left-hand drain tub, I'd be able implement an access panel on the new wall to access the tub drain assembly, similar to what was in place before:

[image: Original access panel for original baththub]

In order to add an access panel for a right-hand drain tub, I'd have to cut into a wall in the hallway, and I'd really like to avoid that.

This setup would also allow for easier access to the existing drain plumping, since I'd just have to shorten the existing drain pipe, instead of extending it to run closer to the wall where the current shower head is placed.

My biggest worry about adjusting the orientation back to a left-hand drain tub involves our bathroom entry door. The door has never been changed, and as you can tell from the pictures, the hinges are pretty rusted:

[image: Bathroom door hinge rust]

I'm unsure if the rust is a product of 65+ years of being in a room without a bathroom fan (we installed one last year), or if the shower head pointing directly at the door caused overspray to rust those hinges.

We're planning to replace the bathroom door during this renovation, so I want to be sure I'm not going to rust out my hinges in a couple years if I put the shower head on the left-hand side instead of keeping it where it's at.

Does anyone have any thoughts about if placing the shower head on the left would cause major issues with the door hinges? Or is it safe to assume the rust is a result of years of no ventilation? I'm hoping to buy a tub soon, but this question has kept me from going through with it, so I thought I'd try and get some advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you already have the pipes by the toilet, left hand.

Answer (score 3):

Rusty hinges should be near to the bottom of your list of considerations for placement because they are inexpensive and easily replaced. Ability to easily operate the valves and comfortably wrangle children in and out of the tub safely (away from the swinging bathroom door), and the access to the plumbing that you illustrated, would be much higher on my list of reasons for location. I would vote left.

Comment: And you can buy stainless steel hinges to eliminate the rust issue

Comment: That's a really fair point. In the grand scheme of things, hinges can be replaced, so it shouldn't be as big of a determining factor as I was making it out to be. Thanks for calling out all those other factors as well! I think I was getting a bit of tunnel vision on this one and failed to account what option would offer the best experience for the folks actually using the tub.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a logistics problem. Ask your wife. Drywall is pretty easy to repair, and nobody wants to look at that dumb access panel. Bury it with nicely finished drywall and cut into it if you ever need access. It's better not to tile the back surface or otherwise make the plumbing inaccessible.

If you don't have confidence in your plumbing skills and you've got copper pipe, then use compression fittings to transition to PEX and use PEX with crimp rings inside the wall.

Comment: That's true. It isn't too tough to cut into drywall, so I should consider just finishing the wall up entirely and avoiding tile in that spot. This house was built with 1 inch thick plaster and metal lath walls, so I always forget how easy it is to cut into normal drywall, haha. Every time I need to cut into a wall now, it's a bit of a chore.

Luckily the plumbing won't be an issue. I just repiped my house w/ my father-in-law this summer using pex-a, so making the supply connections will be pretty easy.